# How to fix old values inside child node which keeps getting overwritten by new value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android and fire base, so the first thing is that inside fire base I can add new value inside my child("post") without problem, but the thing is inside 0-40 seconds when a user try add new post the old user's post gets overwritten by the new user's post and the same thing happens with comments, when a user try to post a comment inside the post.

```
private void SavingPostInformationToDatabase()
{  UsersRef.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String userFullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                String UserName = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                String userProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();

                HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();
                postsMap.put("uid", current_user_id);
                postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
                postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                postsMap.put("description", Description);
                postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl);
                postsMap.put("profileimage", userProfileImage);
                postsMap.put("fullname", userFullName);
                postsMap.put("username", UserName);
                postsMap.put("counter", CountPost);

                PostsRef.child(current_user_id + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    SendUserToMainActivity();
                                    Toast.makeText(PostRecipeActivity.this, "New Post is updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(PostRecipeActivity.this, "Error Occured while updating your post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: okay thanks for pointing out